# display the content of a register in MessageBox win32 (assembly)

Tags: winapi, assembly, messagebox

I would like to know how to display the content of a register in a messageBox in win32 assembly programing, here is an example of what i would like to do :

```
include 'win32ax.inc' ;
MOV DX,01h

start:
   invoke  MessageBox,HWND_DESKTOP,DX,"test",MB_OK
   invoke  ExitProcess,0
.end start
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert it to a string, and then pass its address to MessageBox.

**Edit**: (info update)

I suggest you use [_itoa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx) or [_itoa_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h.aspx) from C-runtime libraries (msvcr*.dll)

Comment: thanks for your quick response, how can i convert it, is there like a function or something like that ??